# renaming an app's package or Activity name?

Tags: adobe-reader

I have searched around, and the only way it seems to run multiple instances of an app would be to rename the app's Activity or package, eg to rename com.adobe.reader.MainActivity to something like com.adobe.reader.myActivity.

Has anyone succeeded in doing anything like this or is there an easier way to run multiple instances of an app?

Comment: You cannot change the app's package or activity name as that will cause a force close - because the application would be looking for the package name and thus would yield *ClassNotFound* exception....

Comment: no. I figured out how to do this today. It is tedious but certainly possible with tools like decompilers and apktool.

Comment: This is a programming-related question and should be asked in StackOverflow.com

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to have multiple instances of the same app (logged in to different accounts)?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/27156)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.guidingtech.com/12252/rename-android-apps-change-icons/). Basically, it involves:

- backup and copy an `apk` to the PC
- use `APK Edit` to edit the `apk`
- copy the `apk` back to the device